# How to get c buffer from ImageMagick Image

Tags: c++, objective-c, imagemagick

I'm using the iPhone port of ImageMagick.  I'm trying to loop through the frames of an animated gif and turn each frame into an UIImage.  I know I can init a UIImage with NSData which I can init with a const void *.  So how to I get the buffer and length of the image?

Here's the code:

```
    MagickReadImage(wand, filename);

        while(MagickHasNextImage(wand)) {
             Image *myImage = GetImageFromMagickWand(wand);
             //HELP ME PLEASE
             const void *myBuff =myImage->blob;  //guessing this is the right way to get the buffer?
             int myLength = ????? //no idea how to get the length
             NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:myBuff length:myLength];
             UIImage myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData]];
             MagickNextImage(wand);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the solution now:

```
    size_t my_size;
    unsigned char * my_image = MagickGetImageBlob(wand, &my_size);
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:my_image length:my_size];
    free(my_image);

    UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```