# ImageMagick in Iphone: how to convert Image object to UIImage in iphone

Tags: iphone, imagemagick

I am trying to create a distortion in image using imageMagick in Iphone.
Following is my code:

```
Image *img = GetImageFromMagickWand(magick_wand);
const double ctrlPts[8] = {150,150,50,50,10,20,90,10};
const size_t q = 4;
ExceptionInfo *d = AcquireExceptionInfo() ;
const RectangleInfo r = {10,10,5,4};
size_t my_size;
Image *distortedImage = DistortImage(img, AffineDistortion, q, ctrlPts, MagickTrue, d);
```

Now I am meshed over here. How to convert this distortedImage object to UIImage object so that I can use that Image.

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258479/how-to-get-c-buffer-from-imagemagick-image

Comment: @Ade: Thanks for reply. But my confusion is that my Image distortedImage not in MagickWand. So how to get the new image `distortedImage`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:distortedImage length:my_size];
free(distortedImage);
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

if you don't know the size try the following:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(initWithBytes:distortedImage);
free(distortedImage);
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Comment: use of undeclared identifier here initWithBytes when getting NSData without knowing size.